# How to drag down formula and change COLUMN references instead of ROWS to make a dynamic list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've searched around a good amount and I have not found a solid answer for this question, despite a few promising looking question titles.

This question here for example: [Drag down formula and change COLUMN references instead of ROWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348825/drag-down-formula-and-change-column-references-instead-of-rows)

Unfortunately only works for specifically referenced cells. I'm working with a data set that is likely to have columns added to it in the future, and I need to pull the first row of these columns dynamically into a vertical list. Because of this, the method accepted as an answer in that question is not a solution for my problem.

I have data coming in like this:

[image: Mock raw data]

and I'm pulling the Course names into a vertical list like this:

[image: mock list]

The thing is, more courses are likely to be added in the future, and I'd like to be able to just drag down my formula to pull them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in cell A10 of the first sheet in your question ...

```
=INDEX($1:$1048576,1,1+ROW(10:10)-10)
```

... and then drag it down!

The formula works by using the current `ROW()` number to calculate the required column number, which is passed into the `INDEX()` function.

Comment: Yes, i just used the existing/data sheet as an example! Assuming your data sheet is called `Sheet1`, paste this into cell **A2** another worksheet ... `=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1048576,1,1+ROW(2:2)-2)`

Comment: If you copy formula to A1 is enough ```=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1;1;ROW())```

Comment: @basic yeah that's much cleaner :0) I had to change the semicolons to commas to make it work because of my location! ... `=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1;1;ROW())`