# Excel COLUMN function to change column instead of row when i drag down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, like I said I have the following formula in excel:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$8,'\Volumes\remax\BDM\Rapoarte : Analize\2023\[Date 2023.xlsx]GCI'!$A:$M,COLUMN(B2),0)
```

so if I drag it down it will return:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$8,'\Volumes\remax\BDM\Rapoarte : Analize\2023\[Date 2023.xlsx]GCI'!$A:$M,COLUMN(B2),0)
=VLOOKUP($A$8,'\Volumes\remax\BDM\Rapoarte : Analize\2023\[Date 2023.xlsx]GCI'!$A:$M,COLUMN(B3),0)
=VLOOKUP($A$8,'\Volumes\remax\BDM\Rapoarte : Analize\2023\[Date 2023.xlsx]GCI'!$A:$M,COLUMN(B4),0)
```

and I need it to return:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$8,'\Volumes\remax\BDM\Rapoarte : Analize\2023\[Date 2023.xlsx]GCI'!$A:$M,COLUMN(B2),0)
=VLOOKUP($A$8,'\Volumes\remax\BDM\Rapoarte : Analize\2023\[Date 2023.xlsx]GCI'!$A:$M,COLUMN(C2),0)
=VLOOKUP($A$8,'\Volumes\remax\BDM\Rapoarte : Analize\2023\[Date 2023.xlsx]GCI'!$A:$M,COLUMN(D2),0)
```

I tried using math formulas for example:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$8,'\Volumes\remax\BDM\Rapoarte : Analize\2023\[Date 2023.xlsx]GCI'!$A:$M,COLUMN(M2)-COLUMN(B2)+1,0)
```

And basically everything else that I know

Comment: Change `COLUMN(B2)` to `ROW(B2)`  they both will return 2 to start but as it is dragged down the row will change to 3 then 4 and so on.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13348825/4961700

Comment: ROW(B2) when i drag it down it will change to ROW(B3) B4 B5 etc

Comment: `ROW(B3)` returns the same thing as `COLUMN(C2)`?

Comment: yes, the thing is it will not update the reference

Comment: COLUMN(B2) is 2.  ROW(B2) is also equal 2.  If you copy/fill down, the next formula will be ROW(B3), which is 3.  Which is what you want--you want the VLOOKUP `COLUMN` indicator to go up by +1 on each subsequent row.  And the `ROW` value does exactly that--it goes up by 1 each row you copy it down.  So you are using the ROW function to create a increment of +1 per row, and then using that as the column index.  No matter what row you are starting in, you want to start with a ROW argument that equals your first column.  So if your first lookup is column 2, then start with ROW(A2) and copy down.

Comment: Woww thanks a lot @MaxR, I was using the incorrect function all this time.Thanks mate I appreciate your help.

Comment: @davidpatron It's counterintuitive.  "why would I use ROW() when I want to increment a column number?"  Because the row number happens to increment by 1 as I fill down.  "But I feel like I am 'lying' to Excel by exploiting the ROW() function to get its fill-down behavior, but then sneakily cheating the system by using that number to actually be my vlookup *column* counter."  Correct, that's *exactly* what we're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COLUMN(B2) is 2. ROW(B2) is also equal 2. If you copy/fill down, the next formula will be ROW(B3), which is 3. Which is what you want--you want the VLOOKUP COLUMN indicator to go up by +1 on each subsequent row. And the ROW value does exactly that--it goes up by 1 each row you copy it down. So you are using the ROW function to create a increment of +1 per row, and then using that as the column index. No matter what row you are starting in, you want to start with a ROW argument that equals your first column. So if your first lookup is column 2, then start with ROW(A2) and copy down. - Max R

Thanks @Max R